# How to return a single owned record with Diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

Actually I'm returing a cloned struct

```
pub fn matrix_first_or_create(&self, schema: String, symbol: String) -> RewardMatrix {
    ....

    let rewards = reward_matrix
        .filter(state.eq(schema.clone()))
        .filter(turn_symbol.eq(symbol.clone()))
        .limit(1)
        .load::<RewardMatrix>(&self.connection)
        .expect("Error loading posts");

    if rewards.len() > 0 {
        return rewards.get(0).unwrap().clone();
    }

    ....
}
```

Is this the right way to handle a result in Diesel? Can I "extract" and own the first and only result from this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need here is the [`.first()`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/query_dsl/trait.RunQueryDsl.html#method.first) method of the [`RunQueryDsl`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/query_dsl/trait.RunQueryDsl.html#) trait.

Here is an example of how it works:

```
let reward: RewardMatrix = reward_matrix
    .filter(state.eq(schema.clone()))
    .filter(turn_symbol.eq(symbol.clone()))
    .first(&self.connection)?;
```

But if your query may not return that row, it’s also good to use the [`.optional()`](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/result/trait.OptionalExtension.html#tymethod.optional) method of `QueryResult`:

```
let reward: Option<RewardMatrix> = reward_matrix
    .filter(state.eq(schema.clone()))
    .filter(turn_symbol.eq(symbol.clone()))
    .first(&self.connection)
    .optional()?;
```

Answer (score 0):

`load` returns a simple owned `Vec<RewardMatrix>`, so any solution for getting an owned element from a `Vec` works here:

```
if let Some(reward) = rewards.into_iter().next() {
    return reward;
}
```

but Diesel also provides better-suited alternatives like `get_result` and [`first`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/query_dsl/trait.RunQueryDsl.html#method.first) that don’t involve `Vec` at all (combine with [`optional`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/result/trait.OptionalExtension.html#tymethod.optional) as recommended in the documentation):

```
let reward = reward_matrix
    .filter(state.eq(&schema))
    .filter(turn_symbol.eq(&symbol))
    .first::<RewardMatrix>(&self.connection)
    .optional()
    .expect("Error loading posts");

if let Some(reward) = reward {
    return reward;
}
```